# How can I return in a ObsevableCollection<T> using C# Linq, all items if no one is selected or just selected items if at least one is selected?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, items

I'm trying to get items in C# in an `ObservableCollection<MyClassSelectable>` using Linq and Lambda in the following cases :

- Returns All items if no one is selected

Or

- Returns just selected items if at least one is selected.

`MyClassSelectable` has a property named `Selected` of `bool` type.

Is it possible to do it, in only one Linq query line ?

Thank you.

Comment: Any particular reason why it NEEDs to be single Linq query?

Comment: Can you share the entire code sample? `Linq` methods return an `IEnumerable` at most cases, you can't return an `ObservableCollection`

Comment: The only need is to have a more compact code and facilitate maintenance without several lines doing the same functional query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can first group by the `Selected` property. This will get you 2 groups if there are selected and not-selected items OR 1 group if all items are either selected or not-selected. Then, order the groups by the selected property. This will put the group with selected items in the first place if there are 2 groups. Then, return the first group.

```
ObservableCollection<MyClassSelectable> myClassesSelectable;

List<MyClassSelectable> result = myClassesSelectable
    // group by the Selected property
    .GroupBy(mcs => mcs.Selected)
    // order (=> true first, false second)
    .OrderByDescending(g => g.Key)
    // return the first
    .FirstOrDefault()
    ?.ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer @Pavel Anikhouski and updating @GregaMohorko answer, the below code does the job rightly.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Test
{
    public class MyClassSelectable
    {
        public bool Selected { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; } = "";
    }

    public class Class1
    {

        public ObservableCollection<MyClassSelectable> myClassesSelectable = new ObservableCollection<MyClassSelectable>();

        public Class1()
        {
            myClassesSelectable.Add(new MyClassSelectable { Selected = true, Name = "Item 1" });
            myClassesSelectable.Add(new MyClassSelectable { Selected = true, Name = "Item 2" });
            myClassesSelectable.Add(new MyClassSelectable { Selected = false, Name = "Item 3" });
            myClassesSelectable.Add(new MyClassSelectable { Selected = false, Name = "Item 4" });

            IEnumerable<MyClassSelectable> myCollection = myClassesSelectable
                            // group by the Selected property
                            .GroupBy(mcs => mcs.Selected)
                            // order (=> true first, false second)
                            .OrderByDescending(g => g.Key)
                            // return the first OR an empty collection if there are no items
                            .FirstOrDefault()
                            ?.ToList();
        }

    }
}
```

- If 2 items are Selected, it returns a list of the two items.
- If no item are Selected, it returns all 4 items.

Thank you very much for your job @GregaMohorko.

Comment: You should probably add a question mark before `ToList()` at the end, because `FirstOrDefault()` can return `null` if there are no items and it will throw `NullReferenceException`. Please take a look at my updated answer.

Comment: Hi @GregaMohorko, you are right. I did the update. Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

```
return new ObservableCollection<MyClassSelectable>(myCol.Any(x => x.Selected)?myCol
.Where(x => x.Selected):myCol)
```

Comment: I tested also this solution. It returns the same result as this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/60318825/12805184

Comment: I don't think this counts as one query. This is just taking advantage of the inline if statement to stack everything into one line.

Answer (score -1):

You can also achieve the same behavoir without using GroupBy().

```
class MainClass {
  public static void Main (string[] args) {
    var myCollection = new ObservableCollection<MyClassSelectable>();

    // Add some items of tyoe MyClassSelectable to myCollection here
    myCollection.Add(new MyClassSelectable() { Selected = true });
    myCollection.Add(new MyClassSelectable() { Selected = false });
    myCollection.Add(new MyClassSelectable() { Selected = true });
    myCollection.Add(new MyClassSelectable() { Selected = true });


    // Now get selected or all items
    var selected = GetSelectedItems(myCollection);

    Console.WriteLine($"Items selected: {selected.Count()}");
  }

  private static IEnumerable<MyClassSelectable> GetSelectedItems(ObservableCollection<MyClassSelectable> coll) {
    var selected = coll.Where(c => c.Selected);
    if (selected.Count() > 0) {
      return selected;
    }
    else {
      return coll;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You are right, but the aim of the question is not reached. It fills several lines of code.

Comment: You are right, but the reason I am suggesting this solution is that you iterate the collection only once instead of iterating through list (to group items) then ordering true and false keys and finally once again transforming whole collection of selected to list. So much overhead for eliminating few lines of code?

Sometimes the shortest solution is not the best one.

Comment: I agree with you. But In my specific case CPU and memory overheads are less important than code clarity.